# Salesforce1 Redirection Issue from Mobile Web Browser

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

On a mobile device with Salesforce1 installed ( Android / iOS) I am getting some strange functionality.

When viewing a visualforce page using standard web browsing ( not in sf1 ) and clicks on a link to a standard record.  ( `https://serverURL/recordId` )

On Android:  one gets option to choose application ( sf1 or web browser).

If one choose web browser everything works fine / redirected correctly.

If one attempt to open in salesforce1 you get a message that says..  Log in to correct org to view this chatter post.  ( strange as i'm already logged in - this might be due to test sandbox ).  You end up at home page or last page visited.  Not the correct referenced url record Id.

On iOS:  no option to choose between sf1 or web..

SF1 loads but again it does not display correct page.  You end up at home page or last page visited same as in Android.

Appears that if the link is in the following format:

`https://customerOrg--testing.cs8.my.salesforce.com/a2JL0000000rFsfMAE` redirects correctly.

On both Android and iOS the SF1 application is bypassed and the related record is loaded into the mobile browser correctly.

but using a relative link in a visualforce page

/a2JL0000000rFsfMAE

or a fully qualified visualforce link

```
 `https://customerOrg--testing--c.cs8.visual.force.com/a2JL0000000rFsfMAE`
```

loads the sf1 app with the incorrect page / last visited page.

I have two issues:

1. Appears SF1 does not render the correct page when a link is launched from a visualforce page.
2. In iOS app the user does not get the option to choose standard web browser and hence is redirect to SF1.  Yet SF1 does not load the correct page.

Issue 1 really causes the headache.   On an Android this is acceptable as we can instruct users to load pages in web.  ( Although though they SHOULD be able to view this record in SF1 ).  In iOS this is unacceptable as the link automatically launches SF1 and dumps user at last page visited.

I know we can tell SF1 to load specific pages via this format: com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId={ObjectId}

This is troublesome as we do not know when the link is generated or until the user clicks the link if SF1 is installed on the device.

Any suggestions!  Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Deep Linking isn't supported in Salesforce1 at this time. :(

Please vote up this idea..

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kyo3AAA